# How to make specific column sum with specific other column condition

Tags: excel, sum

I would like to kwnow what formula should I use for obtainin this result:

[image: Excel]

Want to add columns B+D+F depending on previous column value (if it is A or P)

Comment: Using your provided sample, in cell K4 and copied right: `=SUMIF($A$1:$E$1,K3,$B$1:$F$1)`